# Rooftop lawn on flat roof

Tags: lawn, roof-garden

We are building an extension to our home and the extension has a flat concrete roof.
We would like to plant a lawn on this roof. Structurally the roof can handle the weight but now I have a few growing lawn related queries:

1. What soil depth should we allow for?
2. Are there any specific drainage systems to use?

I've read about specific soils to use and use a shallow rooting grass, however, I'm still not certain on the depth of soil required.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Sounds like a good place for artificial grass. The only sod roofs I have seen were pitched.

Comment: You might want to consider a "green roof" instead, which in your case means a roof that contains primarily sedums. Here's some information: https://www.sempergreen.com/us/solutions/green-roofs/everything-about-sedum. Just from a practical POV, how would you mow a grass roof? The only one I've ever seen was pitched and mowed by goats.

Comment: @Jurp the extension is in a sloped section of the garden to the roof extends existing lawn. I think I may need to go with artificial grass but would have preferred a natural option.

Comment: Well, there are grass-like sedums (e.g. Sedum sexangulare) that make excellent and fast-growing groundcovers. Of course, these bloom (the one I referenced is bright yellow) and then the faded blooms turn brown, so that could be a deal-breaker. One other option would be blue-eyed grass (Sisyrinchium), which looks like grass and also blooms, but in this case the blooms fade to green seedheads and are not particularly noticeable. Not as quick of a groundcover as the sedum: if you were to over-seed you could probably get a lawn "look" in a year or so. Just a couple of other options for you.

Comment: thanks @jurp I will check out the options we have available in our country.